# Issue export table data to CSV file With UTF-8 On Real Host

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I try to export data from MySQL table to CSV file, It Works Will On My Virtual Hosting But When I Upload It On Real Hosting, The Exporting Has The Issue With UTF-8, I Use The Code Below

```
require_once 'config.php';
$questions = questions::getAssoc("SELECT id,question FROM question");
download_csv_results($questions, 'file.csv');
exit();
function download_csv_results($questions , $name)
{
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; 
    filename=file.csv');
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post- 
    check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Pragma: public');
    echo "\xEF\xBB\xBF"; // UTF-8 BOM
    $outstream = fopen("php://output", "wb");
    fputcsv($outstream, array_keys($questions[0]));

    foreach($questions as $question)
    {
        $id = $question['id'];
        fputcsv($outstream, $question);
        $answers = answers::getAssoc("SELECT name,answer,mobile FROM answer WHERE qid=$id");
        foreach ($answers as $answer){
            fputcsv($outstream, $answer);
        }
    }

    fclose($outstream);
}
```

[On Virtual Host](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ru4Kd.png)

[On Real Host](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2nKoF.png)

Comment: header('Content-Encoding: UTF-8');     
header('Content-type: text/csv; charset=UTF-8');    
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Customers_Export.csv');   
echo "\xEF\xBB\xBF";   try this.

Comment: still the same result